# Deploying Docker containers with port-mapping on Mesos/Marathon

Tags: mysql, json, apache, docker, mesos

I am currently working on a team project utilizing Docker with Apache Mesos/Marathon. To deploy MySQL docker containers on Mesos/Marathon, we have to create a JSON file with port mapping. I have searched everywhere on the internet and just can't find any sample JSON file to look on for port mapping. Anyone have done this before?

Comment: Which of the four enormous systems you have mentioned is going to read the JSON?

Comment: What are the four systems? Are you refering to init system (Marathon), cron (Chronos), service discovery (DNS), storage (HDFS)?

Comment: You mentioned Docker, Mesos, Marathon and MySQL in your question.  All of them may do port mapping, and may need to read JSON.  Please narrow down your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's some example Marathon JSON for using Docker's bridged networking mode:

`{
  "id": "bridged-webapp",
  "cmd": "python3 -m http.server 8080",
  "cpus": 0.5,
  "mem": 64.0,
  "instances": 2,
  "container": {
    "type": "DOCKER",
    "docker": {
      "image": "python:3",
      "network": "BRIDGE",
      "portMappings": [
        { "containerPort": 8080, "hostPort": 0, "servicePort": 9000, "protocol": "tcp" },
        { "containerPort": 161, "hostPort": 0, "protocol": "udp"}
      ]
    }
  }
}`

See the "Bridged Networking Mode" section in 
https://mesosphere.github.io/marathon/docs/native-docker.html for more details.

Comment: {
  "id": "mysql1",
  "cmd": "/bin/bash /start.sh",
  "cpus": 0.5,
  "mem": 500,
  "instances": 1,
  "container": {
    "type": "DOCKER",
    "docker": {
      "image": "centos6mysql",
      "network": "BRIDGE",
      "portMappings": [
        { "containerPort": 3306, "hostPort": 0, "servicePort": 0, "protocol": "tcp" }
      ]
    }
  }
}

Comment: This is how I create the JSON file. However, after running the JSON file, it will just keep showing the Deploying task on my Marathon UI and my containers will keep failing to run.

Comment: It may help to pre-fetch the docker images on each slave, so that Mesos doesn't time out waiting for the `docker pull` to complete. You may also want to increase the `executor_registration_timeout`, since that includes the expected docker pull time. Example: `echo "5mins" | sudo tee /etc/mesos-slave/executor_registration_timeout`

Comment: Also, I think you'll want to set a non-0 servicePort, as this is the cluster-wide port on which you expect to be able to locate your service, if using haproxy or similar for service discovery.